# Is it possible to use Tri-tone sound in my application?

Tags: iphone, audio

Is it possible to use iPhone sound(bundle) in my application

if yes, can you give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are jailbroken, you can find the sound effects in `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/`.

But whether you're allowed to use these sounds or not should be a legal question.